# Pig UDF to write to a file to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I would like to read a complete file through a Pig UDF and then prepare an output file using PrintWriter library in Java and store it on HDFS.

Is this possible,

Steps followed

1) I am able to read the input file in the UDF. Prepare a HashMap from that file.[ACHIEVED]

2) write the data to an output file by filtering the input file. The filtration is done using the HashMap[YET TO BE ACHIEVED]

Can anyone help in my step2.

Aim is to create a file in the Pig UDF and write to that file.

Thanks,

Regards,
Dheeraj Rampally.

Answer (score 1):

No Problem...I have found an alternative for this.. Instead of writing into a file I am now returning a Databag from Pig UDF

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution. Can you please share how you are returning a Bag and processing it later?